# How to change #import "..." into #import <...> in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I have this problem with a library. I want to add it to my Objective C (iOS) project, but their docs don't say how to do that. I simply copied it over. Now their main file has this:

```
#include <LIB/Class1.h>
#include <LIB/Class2.h>
...
```

It didn't work for me, so I changed each <> to "":

```
#include "LIB/Class1.h"
#include "LIB/Class2.h"
...
```

And with this syntax everything works fine, I can use the lib. I guess it's not a good practice, though. How should I add a library to a project so that it works without this modification?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xcode Build Setting, Header Search Paths (HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS) affects search path of #include <foo.h>, User Header Search Paths (USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS) affects search path of #include "foo.h".

So, set HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS for your library's header path, #include <LIB/Class1.h> should be work.

Also, Always Search User Paths (ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS) setting can change behavior for search path #include <foo.h>. When ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS is YES, #include <LIB/Class1.h> should be work as well.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you said (HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS + ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS) but I still had to add all the files into my project. Is it normal?

Comment: need not to add files into your project. How do you set HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS and how are your project path and library path?

Answer (score 0):

Add path to the libpath... "" relative from source and <>relative from the external libs

Answer (score 0):

`ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS` is deprecated now & should be avoided. Explicitly set

- `USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` for `".h"` include syntax header files.
- `SYSTEM_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` for `<.h>` include syntax header files.
- `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`: for fallback of `USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` for compilers which don't support separate include paths.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/itcaec37c2a6?sub=deved642222b